# Merge or join one data table with one tbl in R

Tags: r, join, data.table, tibble

I'm trying to merge one tbl with local data.table in R but couldn't figure that out.

The tbl is a huge data table with 3 billion rows of records from Amazon Redshiftand while data.table is the reference table I read into R from a txt file using data.table.
I would like to merge this lookup table into the data table for further summary, however, this failed to proceed and come back with error

```
Error in UseMethod("op_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'op_vars' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Given the size of the data table, it is NOT possible to load it into R memory(My 48G memory wasn't enough for this task), so I have to use dyply tbl to query this table.  My questions are:

1. How to merge one tbl with a data.table if it is possible?
2. Is there a better way to handle huge data from redshift directly using data.table? if not, are there better way than what I did?

Thanks so much!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
# tbl point to the data 
concept <- con %>% tbl(in_schema('database','concept'))
concept_l <- concept %>% filter(id=='Measurement')
# change local lookup file into tbl
loincs <- setattr(loinc,"class",c('tbl','tbl_lazy',"tbl_Redshift","tbl_dbi","tbl_sql"))
# merge info into large data table for further process               
concept_c <- left_join(concept_l,loincs,by=c('concept_code'='code'),copy=T)
Error in UseMethod("op_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'op_vars' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Comment: You could use filter on the `concept_code` column to select the needed rows only

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I added that code and other condition in the filter, it won't work.